# Error message with rangeslider in IE9 (JQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, compatibility, rangeslider

This (very basic) page:
http://www.marianotomatis.it/test.php
renders properly on **Chrome** and **Firefox** but on **IE9** it stops on this line:

```
h=a.data(e.get(0),"mobileSlider").slider
```

of the script http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js
with the message "Impossible to retrieve "slider" property of a null or undefine reference".

This is the complete code of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='A' name='A'>
 <div data-role="rangeslider">
    <label for="B">Range</label>
    <input type="range" name="B" id="B" min="0" max="100">
    <label for="C">Range</label>
    <input type="range" name="C" id="C" min="0" max="100">
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you see any reason for the problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. I'm sure it has something to do with  your browser mode or document standards.

Comment: IE9 doesn't support the `range` input type, could that be causing an issue?

Comment: Maybe try the lastest stable version of jquery mobile: 1.3.1  http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: @Ohgodwhy for me using IE9 mode in IE10, i have same issue as OP. BTW, it works on IE10

Comment: @roasted very odd. Standard OOB IE9 here, no flaws reported, doc/browser mode set to IE9 and security set at medium. I wonder what my difference could be.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy well, this is strange! Are you on win7 too? {even i don't think OS changing anything here}

Comment: @roasted Great! Updating to the 1.3.1 I have solved the problem.

Comment: @Roasted Yep. looks like this has been resolved anyway, but really odd.

Comment: @roasted Unfortunately also 1.3.1 does not work properly. Using the non minified version, it stops on this line:

_sliderFirst = $.data( _inputFirst.get(0), "mobileSlider" ).slider
**Impossible to retrieve "slider" property of a null or undefine reference**

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar question to another asked against jQuery Mobile v1.3.1 "[Rangeslider rendering badly in some IE (JQueryMobile 1.3.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402539/rangeslider-rendering-badly-in-some-ie-jquerymobile-1-3-1)"

I was able to discover a fix for this in jQuery Mobile v1.3.2 and have posted my answer on the linked question above.

Answer (score 0):

earthdesigner found a solution to this problem on https://stackoverflow.com/a/18021916/1545905

Add data-type='range' to the range input.