# Rangeslider rendering badly in some IE (JQueryMobile 1.3.1)

Tags: jquery-mobile

This very basic page: http://www.marianotomatis.it/test.php
does not render correctly in "some" IE versions.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head><title>Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-    1.3.1.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="A" name="A">
 <div data-role="rangeslider">
    <label for="B">Range</label>
    <input type="range" name="B" id="B" min="0" max="100">
    <label for="C">Range</label>
    <input type="range" name="C" id="C" min="0" max="100">
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It stops on the script **jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js** in this line:

```
_sliderFirst = $.data( _inputFirst.get(0), "mobileSlider" ).slider,
```

with a **SCRIPT5007** error ("Unable to get value of the property 'slider': object is null or undefined.")

I am using IE10 to debug and I have tested some combinations of Browser Mode (BM) and Document Mode (DM), to check the bad combinations. Hope this helps:

BM=IE10 DM=Standard [OK]
BM=IE9 DM=Standard [OK]
BM=IE8 DM=Standard [OK]
BM=IE7 DM=Standard [OK]
BM=IE10 DM=Non standard [OK]
BM=IE9 DM=Non standard [OK]
BM=IE8 DM=Non standard [OK]
BM=IE7 DM=Non standard [OK]
**BM=IE10 DM=Standard IE9 [Error]

BM=IE9 DM=Standard IE9 [Error]

BM=IE8 DM=Standard IE9 [Error]

BM=IE7 DM=Standard IE9 [Error]

BM=IE10 DM=Standard IE8 [Error]

BM=IE9 DM=Standard IE8 [Error]

BM=IE8 DM=Standard IE8 [Error]

BM=IE7 DM=Standard IE8 [Error]

BM=IE10 DM=Standard IE7 [Error]

BM=IE9 DM=Standard IE7 [Error]

BM=IE8 DM=Standard IE7 [Error]

BM=IE7 DM=Standard IE7 [Error]**

I have also tried to debug it with IE8 and it renders the page correctly.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I got rid of the errors in Internet Explorer when I've added data-type="range" to the inputs:

```
<input type="range" data-type="range" name="B" id="B" min="0" max="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a similar question to another asked against jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 "[Error message with rangeslider in IE9 (JQuery Mobile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796841/error-message-with-rangeslider-in-ie9-jquery-mobile)"

I've been able to reproduce this issue in jQuery Mobile v1.3.2 in IE10 (including WP8) and Chrome 28.

After a little digging in the JQM combined JS file, I found that the logic in several places is calling something like `$.data( _inputFirst.get(0), "mobileSlider" ).slider` if you step into that call stack you'll find at one point it checks for a variable to be undefined and if it is then is transposes the key (`"mobileSlider"`) to camel-case and checks again. In this case the original key was camel-case and if it had been all lower-case with a hyphen (`"mobile-slider"`), it would have not failed.

To correct this issue in JQM v1.3.2, I've replaced the instances of `"mobileSlider"` with `"mobile-slider"` and now I have the expected behavior and working sliders and range sliders again.

Here are the lines and line numbers on which I've made the above change.

1. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(7861):           _sliderFirst = $.data( _inputFirst.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).slider,
2. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(7862):           _sliderLast = $.data( _inputLast.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).slider,
3. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(7863):           firstHandle = $.data( _inputFirst.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).handle,
4. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(7919):           $.data( this._inputFirst.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).dragging = true;
5. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(7920):           $.data( this._inputFirst.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).refresh( event );
6. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(7932):           $.data( otherSlider.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).dragging = true;
7. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(7933):           $.data( otherSlider.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).refresh( event );
8. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(8006):           $.data( otherSlider.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).handle.focus();
9. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(8014):           $.data( thisSlider.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).handle.css( "z-index", 1 );
10. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(8015):          $.data( otherSlider.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).handle.css( "z-index", 0 );
11. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(8017):          $.data( otherSlider.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).handle.css( "z-index", "" );
12. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(8018):          $.data( thisSlider.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).handle.css( "z-index", "" );
13. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(8029):          var min = parseInt( $.data( this._inputFirst.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).handle.get(0).style.left, 10 ),
14. jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js(8030):          max = parseInt( $.data( this._inputLast.get(0), "**mobileSlider**" ).handle.get(0).style.left, 10 ),